# Unserialize dados Codeigniter - Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Através do objeto `obj_form`, eu exibo no formulário os dados do banco:

```
//Objeto do formulário
function obj_form() {   
    $('[name="id"]').val(obj_permissao.id); 
    $('[name="txt_nome"]').val(obj_permissao.nome);
    $('[name="txt_descricao"]').val(obj_permissao.descricao);   
    $('[name="txt_permissoes"]').val(obj_permissao.permissoes);
    $('[name="sel_grupo"]').val(obj_permissao.grupo);
    $('[name="txt_bgcor"]').val(obj_permissao.bgcor);
    $('[name="sel_situacao"]').val(obj_permissao.situacao);
}
```

Na linha `$('[name="txt_permissoes"]').val(obj_permissao.permissoes);`, existem dados serializados, que traz como resultado:

> `a:8:s:8:"aCliente";s:1:"1";s:8:"eCliente";s:1:"1";s:8:"dCliente";s:1:"1";s:8:"vCliente";s:1:"1";s:9:"aOperador";s:1:"1";s:9:"eOperador";s:1:"1";s:9:"dOperador";s:1:"1";s:9:"vOperador";s:1:"1";}`

A questão é: Como posso **deserializar** somente esta linha e checar os `checkbox` abaixo se valor for igual 1.

```
<tbody>
   <tr>                                             
      <td>Cliente</td>                                              
      <td><input id="" name="aCliente" class="marcar cursor" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
      <td><input id="" name="eCliente" class="marcar cursor" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
      <td><input id="" name="dCliente" class="marcar cursor" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
      <td><input id="" name="vCliente" class="cursor"        type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Operador</td>
      <td><input id="" name="aOperador" class="marcar cursor" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
      <td><input id="" name="eOperador" class="marcar cursor" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
      <td><input id="" name="dOperador" class="marcar cursor" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
      <td><input id="" name="vOperador" class="cursor"        type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: pelo que entendi não tem nada a ver com o Codeigniter e sim na parte do JS, é isso? Se for isso e estiver usando jquery, da uma olhada nesse link, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ que pode te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Quero informa que resolvi da seguinte forma:
Utilizei o [plugin php-unserialize-js](https://github.com/bd808/php-unserialize-js).

E converti a string em objeto:
`var permissoes = phpUnserialize(obj_permissao.permissoes);`
`console.log(permissoes);`

Resultado:
`aCliente:null
 aOperador:null
 dCliente:null
 dOperador:null
 eCliente:null
 eOperador:null
 vCliente:"1"
 vOperador:"1"`